# Count $sum by item in array

Tags: mongodb, pipeline

I have a (here simplified) collection of documents:

```
{
   _id: oid,
   unique: ['col', 34875, 34, '_some_id'],
   otherfields: 'some text',
}
{
   _id: oid,
   unique: ['col', 34875, 17, '_some_other_id'],
   otherfields: 'other book',
}
{
   _id: oid,
   unique: ['afs', 24, 1, '_some_id'],
   otherfields: 'other book',
}
```

So: the *unique* array is a somewhat complex identifier, containing four items, where the combination makes it unique.

Now i want to group and count the items in the collection by the third element *unique.2* in the *unique* array. First filtered by unique.0 and unique.1

```
pipeline = [  
    {'$match': {'unique.0': 'col', 'unique.1': 34875},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$uilist.2', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
]
```

Using Python Pymongo. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "unique.0": "col",
      "unique.1": 34875
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$unique",
          2
        ]
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Changes:

- The original aggregation is missing a closing bracket for the `$match`
- Th original aggregation references a `uilist` in the `$group`, but that field doesn't exist in your sample documents.
- Relatedly, the way you access elements in an array while inside an aggregation is by using [the `$arrayElemAt` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/).

See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FjS43eZrDSw)

Comment: $arrayAtElement... that was the one. Spot on. Thanks.